# How limits should be understood in large deviation theory

Tags: calculus, probability, large-deviation-theory

In general we say that a function $f\left(n\right)$ satisfies a large deviation principle if:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}-\frac{1}{n}\ln \left[f\left(n\right)\right]=F
\end{equation}
What we really want to mean for practical purposes is that:
\begin{equation}
f\left(n\right)\approx e^{-nF}
\end{equation}
but in textbooks it is found as:
\begin{equation}
f\left(n\right)\asymp e^{-nF}
\end{equation}
where the symbol "$\asymp$" means:
\begin{equation}
a_{n}\asymp b_{n}\Leftrightarrow\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln b_{n}
\end{equation}
Now my question is:

> How can I go from the first equation to the third one?

Just to mention, in general it should be true that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}-\frac{1}{n}\ln \left[f\left(n\right)\right]\neq -\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln\left[f\left(n\right)\right]}{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n}
\end{equation}
right?

Comment: "What we really want to mean for practical purposes is that: f(n)≈e−nF" No, what we really want to mean for practical purposes is the (correct) limit statement just above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the first equation is fulfilled. To prove the third one, we have to check whether 
$$ \def\li{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n \log}\li f(n) = \li e^{-nF}\tag 1 $$
But 
$$ \li e^{-nF} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n \cdot (-nF) = -F $$
hence (1) reads 
$$ \li f(n) = -F $$ and that is true by your first equation.